# Getting odd number between two number

Tags: c++

The rule is I need to display the odd number between two number that the user inputted.

But my code have problem.

For example when i input: 3 and 11
The output is 5 7 9 11

11 should not be included because that's what the user input even it is odd number. The rule is between. 5 7 9 is my target.

i'm thinking if it's because of my formula or the way i increment it.

First try: i increment numOne before "if"

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numOne,numTwo;

    cout << "Please Enter First Number : ";
    cin >> numOne;
    cout << "Please Enter Second Number ( Should be greater than first number) : " ;
    cin >> numTwo;

    cout << "Odd Numbers Between are: ";

    while (numOne<numTwo)
    {
          numOne++;
         if ( numOne % 2 == 1)

            {
                cout<<numOne<<" ";
            }
         
        }


return 0;
}
```

The output is: 5 7 9 11

-still wrong because 11 should not be include- :(

**Second try: i increment numOne below "if"

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numOne, numTwo;

    cout << "Please Enter First Number : ";
    cin >> numOne;
    cout << "Please Enter Second Number ( Should be greater than first number) : " ;
    cin >> numTwo;

    cout << "Odd Numbers Between are: ";

    while (numOne<numTwo)
    {
        if  ( numOne % 2 == 1)
        {
            cout<<numOne<<" ";
        }

        numOne++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is: 3 5 7 9

-before 11 is the problem but now it's gone when i incremented below.. But it is still wrong because 3 should not be included also- :(

3 and 11 is the users input.. Even it is odd it should not be included.. Only the odd number "between them". "5 7 9"

Comment: Why did you choose to do a `while` loop, when the easier, more plain method would be to use a `for` loop?

Comment: Your conditions in the `if()` are pretty much nonsense. Check again what the `%` operator exactly does.

Comment: Ow im sorry.. i forgot to mention that i should only use while loop.. It's a rule given to us

Comment: This is a really good candidate for either stepping through in the debugger, watching the value of each variable, or adding lots of print statements. All you need to understand is why your first example printed `11`, right? You can figure that out on a piece of paper. When you know _why_ it printed that value, you'll know what to change to stop it.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second attempt works if increment `numOne` before you start.

```
numOne++;

while (numOne < numTwo)
{
    if (numOne % 2 == 1 || numOne % 2 == -1)
    {
        cout << numOne << " ";
    }

    numOne++;
}
```

But, you may wish to use a `for` loop.

```
for (int i = numOne + 1; i < numTwo; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) continue;

    cout << i << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you make sure to start on the first correct number, you can skip the even numbers entirely and worry less about ordering.

```
int start = (numOne % 2 == 0) ? numOne + 1 : numOne + 2;
for (int i = start; i < numTwo; i += 2)
{
    cout << i << ' ';
}
```

If you must use `while` (which is inappropriate for a loop with a fixed incrementation, and you should only do it to satisfy your teacher),

```
int i = (numOne % 2 == 0) ? numOne + 1 : numOne + 2;
while (i < numTwo)
{
    cout << i << ' ';
    i += 2;
}
```

or even

```
if (numOne % 2 == 0)
{
    numOne = numOne + 1;
}
else
{
    numOne = numOne + 2;
}
while (numOne < numTwo)
{
    cout << i << ' ';
    i += 2;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `int start = numOne + (numOne % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 2;`

Comment: @Chris I personally  find that less obvious. I also considered `int start = numOne + 1 + numOne % 2;`, which some might prefer.